# Освобождается ли куча от массива

Tags: c++

Пусть у меня есть следующая функция:

```
int func(void)
{
    std::vector<int> vec1;
    vec1.push_back(10);
    std::vector<int> vec2(vec1.begin(), vec1.end() );
    return 0;
}
```

Как я понимаю после вызова vec1 и vec2 освобождаются из стэка, как локальные переменные. А освобождается ли куча от массивов, на которые указывают vec1 и vec2 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Память, выделенная под хранение элементов вектора, освобождается, т.к. деструктор локальных объектов вызывается автоматически при выходе из метода

[RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii):

> The C++ library classes that manage their own resources follow RAII:
>   std::string, std::vector, std::thread, and many others acquire their
>   resources in constructors (which throw exceptions on errors), release
>   them in their destructors (which never throw), and don't require
>   explicit cleanup.

[Деструктор объекта вектор](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/~vector):

> Уничтожает контейнер. После вызова деструктора высвобождается
>   используемая память. Обратите внимание, что если элементы являются
>   указателями, объекты, на которые они указывают не уничтожаются.